# create random numberbetween 2 number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers

i want to create random number between 2 number in vb.net
for example : a=10 , b=50 , c= recive from input box
i want to create random number between a , b Provided that the number of times C
and any time , new random number greater than old random number

Comment: When you say the new random number must be greater than the old random number do you mean that it should be greater than the first random number generated of the most recent random number generated? Or just a list sorted into increasing numeric order?

Answer (score 0):

To create a random number between two numbers you can simply use the Random() class. An example of this would be as follows:

Dim a As Integer = 10
Dim b As Integer = 50
Dim c As Integer //get the input from input box  
Dim d As Integer
Dim ran As New Random()
d = ran.Next(a,b)

// as for "Provided that the number of times C and any time , new random number greater than old random number" I am not sure I understand could you clarify?
As for this you could simply make a new variable, use an if statement,and if > than d then you could save this into a new variable or array.

Comment: thank you very much . for example after create random Then number of C i want to sort from A to Z Number /// example : 13,18,23,29,31,38,42,44,46,49

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you simply want to create a list of `c` random numbers within the range of `a` to `b` this function will return a list of integers sorted in ascending order

```
Private Function GenerateRandomNumbers(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim numberList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim rnd As New Random
    For i As Integer = 1 To c
        numberList.Add(rnd.Next(a, b))
    Next
    numberList.Sort()
    Return numberList
End Function
```

To use it do something like this

```
Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)
numbers = GenerateRandomNumbers(1, 50, 50)
```